# Firebase 3.1.0 on Nodejs + iOS client custom User Authentication: ERROR_INVALID_CUSTOM_TOKEN

Tags: ios, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm also getting the following error: "The custom token format is incorrect. Please check the documentation." on my iOS client device. 
On my nodejs server, I have my tokenGenerating function as:

```
var credentials = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./firebaseAuthCredentials.json'));
var time_now = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
var token = jwt.sign(
    {
        aud: 'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/google.identity.identitytoolkit.v1.IdentityToolkit',
        iat: time_now,
        exp: time_now + (3600),
        iss: credentials.client_email,
        sub: credentials.client_email,
        uid: userId,
    }, credentials.private_key,
    {
        algorithm: 'RS256'
    }
);

debug(token);

return token;
```

I first tried using the Firebase SDK for nodejs, but I'm also getting the same error on my iOS client...

Comment: didnt get why are you using `jwt.sign` if you could use `firebase.auth().createCustomToken(userId)`.

Comment: That was what I meant when I said "I first tried using the Firebase SDK for nodejs". I should have made that clearer.

Comment: and how did you try to validate the token in your ios application?

Comment: `let firebaseAuthToken = Utilities.FireBaseCustomTokenFromData(JSON($0.data))
                FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithCustomToken(firebaseAuthToken)  { (user, error) ... }`

Comment: I was just able to get it working! Generating a new JSON from firebase, and using that one did the trick. It now works with both `firebase.auth().createCustomToken(userId)` and the code above.